# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value canot be null.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I receive the `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'` error when implementing search in Asp.net MVC.

```
public static Collection<Video> vList = VideoRepository.GetCollection();
List<Video> listofvideos = new List<Video>
public ActionResult Index(string item)
{
  foreach (Video movie in vList)
  {
    if (movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(item))
    {
     listofvideos.add(movie);
    }
  }
 return view(listofvideos);
}
```

Comment: Well this code has typos. Fix that first. It makes it hard to suggest solutions (e.g. new List<Video>(); ). Which line is the error thrown on? What is the rest of the exception? Are you sure "item" is not null? Did you put a break point?

Comment: and the Microsoft created break point for this time

Answer (score 0):

probably it happen when vList is null

check that not be null

```
    public static Collection<Video> vList = VideoRepository.GetCollection();
List<Video> listofvideos = new List<Video>
public ActionResult Index(string item)
{
//add check
if(vList ==null)
{
   return Content("no thing!!")
}
foreach (Video movie in vList)
{
if (movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(item))
{
listofvideos.add(movie);
}
}
return view(listofvideos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears your listOfVideos isn't being instaniated correctly.

```
List<Video> listofvideos = new List<Video>
```

should be

```
List<Video> listofvideos = new List<Video>();
```